# Integrate sidekiq uniqe jobs with activerejob

Tags: sidekiq, rails-activejob

I would like to enforce uniqueness of a sidekiq job using sidekiq unique jobs and activejob. On the documentation for [sidekiq unique jobs](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs) it says

```
Usage with ActiveJob

Sidekiq.default_worker_options = {
  unique: :until_executing,
  unique_args: ->(args) { [ args.first.except('job_id') ] }
}
```

Which is totally non-descriptive. Which file does this go in, and how do I attach these options to a job if I want to set the options on a per-job basis? How do I modify the job? An example of how to use this with activejob would be much appreciated as the documentation is not understandable.

Comment: You should open an issue in that repo asking them to improve the documentation rather than complaining about it here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like ActiveJob is not supported in [latest version](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs/blob/bc2637b04696793f4a8bd79e58517d163bafbf96/README.md).

> [ActiveJob officially not supported][48]

One can use https://github.com/veeqo/activejob-uniqueness